# How to solve my PDE's in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, pde

I need to solve a set of 5 PDEs for functions $u(x,t)$.

I looked up [the Matlab function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/partial-differential-equations.html?refresh=true#f1-697343) `pdepe`. It looked perfect for my case, until I read the line:

> $f(x,t,u,\partial u/\partial x)$ is a flux term and $s(x,t,u,\partial u/\partial x)$ is a source term. The flux term must depend on $\partial u/\partial x$.

In my problem for 4/5 of my equations $f(x,t,u,\partial u/\partial x)$ doesn't depend on $\partial u/\partial x$, and in 1/5 of my equations $f(x,t,u,\partial u/\partial x)=0$. In my equations, there's no second derivative of $u$ with respect to $x$.

- Does this mean i can't use pdepe in order to obtain a solution for my problem?

Oddly enough, in [the link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pdepe.html) for the `pdepe` function, that line I mentioned before:

> ...The flux term must depend on $\partial u/\partial x$.

does not appear there. also, I would expect that since having $f(x,t,u,\partial u/\partial x)$ that does not depend on $\partial u/\partial x$ is just a special case, it wouldn't in any way prevent me from obtaining a solution.

- So all in all, I want to know if I can use `pdepe` even if $f(x,t,u,\partial u/\partial x)$ does not depend on $\partial u/\partial x$?
- If not, what would happen if I try to solve it anyways? and what other method I can use to solve my set of PDEs?

My equations look like this:

Let us use the form of matlab:

`c(x,t,u,∂u/∂x)∂u/∂t=(x^−m)*∂/∂x((x^m)*f(x,t,u,∂u/∂x))+s(x,t,u,∂u/∂x)`.

(`u` is a vector with 5 components, as I have 5 equations)

I have `m=0` in all of  my equations.

```
eq. 1: c=1, f=0, s=A(u)

eq. 2: c=1, f=-u(2).*B(u(4)), s=C(u) 

eq. 3: c=1, f=-u(3).*B(u(5)), s=C(u) 

eq. 4: c=1./B(u(4)), f=-u(4), s=D(u) 

eq. 5: c=1./B(u(5)), f=-u(5), s=E(u)
```

Where `A`,`B`,`C`,`D`,`E` are some functions of `u=[u(1);u(2);u(3);u(4);u(5)]` but not of `x`,`t`,`du/dx`

it's important to note that for a 1st order ODE it can always be chosen that f=0, so that all of the terms can go into s (and in that case, obviously f does not depend on du/dx). here i just chose a convinient way to represent my equations.

Comment: If you can't get that Matlab function working, you can always solve the PDEs doing a simple finite difference based algorithm (if you're working on simple domains) You'd have to work out the math and algorithms for your particular PDEs, though.

Comment: i didn't actually try getting it working yet, because i didn't wanna write the whole code knowing in advance it might not work after seeing that dreadful line "The flux term must depend on ∂u/∂x.". i came here to find out if any1 knows if it might still work if f(x,t,u,∂u/∂x) does not depend on ∂u/∂x. also, is there any other function like pdepe in matlab that is designed to solve pdes?

Comment: What is your PDE system?

Comment: i really don't wanna write a code from scratch that solves the pde's. (by the way how do i put line spaces on these sub comments?)

Comment: i've added the form of my equations to my initial post.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is that the `pdepe` function does not strictly require that the flux
term be a function of $\partial u/\partial x$ or that the pde even contain a flux term.

However,  `pdepe` is designed to work best for this case. The"pe" in the function
name stands for parabolic-elliptic; this is the class of PDE it was designed for. Based on
your description, your system of PDE is likely hyperbolic. How well  `pdepe` will work
in your case depends on the specific equations and boundary conditions.

The numerical solution of hyperbolic PDEs can be quite challenging. Many books and papers
have been written on this topic. However, many of the basic numerical techniques for
solving hyperbolic PDEs rely on adding some "artificial diffusion" to the equations. 
In 1D this amounts to adding a small flux term that **does** depend on 
$\partial u/\partial x$. You can achieve the same effect by doing this manually in 
 `pdepe`. The downside of this approach is that some experimentation is required
to determine the right amount of artificial diffusion; too much and the solution may
be overly smeared out, too little and the solution will show some undesirable oscillations.

If you want to know more, you might take a look at this classic text by Strikwerda:
[http://www.amazon.com/Difference-Schemes-Partial-Differential-Equations/dp/0898715679](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0898715679)

Core MATLAB doesn't have a function designed specifically for hyperbolic PDEs. But Shampine, one
of the authors of `pdepe`, has written such a function for MATLAB and it can be downloaded here:

http://faculty.smu.edu/shampine/current.html
(See the section titled Hyperbolic PDEs)

Comment: i've added the general form of my equations to my initial post. based on that, do you think i should still use pdepe ( without adding any extra terms to my equations ) or try and use the function in the link you gave here?

Comment: It is really impossible to say anything definitive based on such a vague description of your PDE system. As @nicoguaro already asked, you should   show your equations, boundary conditions, and initial conditions. But, as a guess, I expect you will need to add some artificial diffusion to solve your system with pdepe.

Comment: i updated my initial post to a more specific form of the equations. but for the purpose of providing an answer, does it really matter which function of u each of the terms A,B,C,D,E are? isn't all that matters is that they are analytic continuous functions and that do not depends on x,t,du/dx. i just don't wanna go into unnecessary details. the boundary/initial conditions i cant provide yet because i dont have them yet. this set of equations describe a physical system (not just some mathematical problem) so i would have to think and try different kinds of initial/boundary conditions.

Comment: as i said in the previous comment, this is a physical problem, so adding additional terms that might provide a more accurate solution would seem unnatrual to me, but i could be wrong. so, given that, which of the 2 options is better for me?

Comment: also, will a program like Mathematica will have an easier time solving those PDEs? and if you think it's really necessary for me to write explicitly all of my equations, i will do so (if thats the case, can you point me as to how i write the equations in a form that is easy to read like i've seen in other threads, for example here : http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1836/matlab-solving-u-t-fu-u-xx-gu-u-x-hu-u?rq=1 )

Comment: Many of the participants in this group
are interested in "physical problems." But
many are still confused about the details of the equations
you are trying to solve. Is this a fluid flow problem? If so,
the solution and numerical techniques are
different if the flow is incompressible
flow at 1 mph compared with hypersonic flow at Mach 25.
If you are looking for a black-box PDE solver that will
automatically provide a solution, I think you will be
disappointed.  I suggest you look
more at numerical techniques for solving 
hyperbolic PDEs  and do some numerical experiments (e.g. 
pdepe).

Comment: my equations are a combination of maxwell's equations and relativistic fluid equations for electrons and positrons. my functions are the electric field, the densities, and the velocities. is it not more preferable to use that function for solving 1st order pde's (hpde) in that link you provided? because after all for pdepe "f(x,t,u,∂u/∂x) does not depend on ∂u/∂x". by the way, why wasn't hpde implented in matlab?

Comment: since this is only a 1st order system of 5 pde's so i assumed there is a simple way to solve it using matlab already built-in functions.  can you please give me a  more definitive answer for my questions: 1.) hpde or pdepe? 2.) is there a reason not to trust hpde, because it wasn't implemented in matlab? 3.) in pdepe: if i have f=0 in all of my equations (i can set it this way because there is no 2nd derivative of u with respect to x) then the pdepe function of matlab will work well better than using f that doesn't depend on du/dx?

Comment: 4.) will a program like Mathematica will have an easier time solving those PDEs?

Comment: If I were solving this problem, I'd try every PDE solver I had access to starting with pdepe. In pdepe, I suggest defining a flux term instead of lumping everything into s. By the way, the Shampine hyperbolic software is not a single solver but rather a collection of methods. The idea is that you experiment with the different methods to find one you like.

Comment: i have no idea what flux term to introduce ( that won't affect the solution but still allow pdepe to work well ). its abit frustrating that they didn't make a pde solver for 1st order pdes. does it make sense do use pdepe for a 1st order pde (by setting f=0, without a flux term at all) ? because if "the flux term must depend on ∂u/∂x", then the structure of the pde that pdepe can solve c(x,t,u,∂u/∂x)∂u/∂t=(x^−m)*∂/∂x((x^m)*f(x,t,u,∂u/∂x))+s(x,t,u,∂u/∂x) does not match a 1st order pde.

Comment: could you please provide an answer for my other questions? thanks.

Comment: sigh, it looks like you're ignoring my comments. could you please atleast answer me this one critical question? : maybe i'm wrong but it looks like that for some reason the hpde function doesn't save the solution at all times, but only at the final time. so i really dont have u(x,t) but only u(x,t_final) (and u(x,t_initial) of course). so if i actually want u(x,t) i should make some kind of a loop that in each iteration solve only from u(x,t_n) to u(x,t_n+dt)? im afraid something like that would be very inefficient.  am i missing something?